# C#, generate HttpPost sent to a MVC 2 Action with a model as the parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, post, httpwebrequest

I want to build an HTTP post that will send data and automatically bind the data into the model.  I'm having an issue getting this to work, however, as the model comes up empty.  I am using mvc 2.

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest request)
{
    //...do stuff
}
```

and here's how I am building the request.

```
private static string Url(string action, string controller)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Settings.Default.MobileServiceUrl, controller, action);
    }

    public static string Post(string action, string controller, NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
        string url = Url(action, controller);

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();

            client.UploadValues(url, parameters);

            byte[] respBytes = client.UploadValues(url, fields);

            return client.Encoding.GetString(respBytes);
        }
    }
```

Here's the model class

```
public class AuthenticateRequest
{
    public string SiteAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
}
```

here is the sample data

```
NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();
        fields.Add("SiteAbbreviation", "ABCD");
        fields.Add("Username", "username");
        fields.Add("Password", "password");
        fields.Add("AdminPassword", "password");

        var json = HttpRequestHelper.Post("Authenticate", "Account", fields);

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticateRequest>(json);
```

EDIT:

If you are wondering why I am doing this, My mvc app is a rest api that returns json for everything. I am trying to build a test project to test my controller methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

```
public class AuthenticateRequest
{
    public string SiteAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest request)
{
    //...do stuff
}
```

the following should most definitely work:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var fields = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "SiteAbbreviation", "ABCD" },
        { "Username", "username" },
        { "Password", "password" },
        { "AdminPassword", "password" }
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues(
        "http://foo.com/someController/authenticate", 
        fields
    );
    // TODO: do something with the result
    // if it is a JSON object deserialize it back to a model
}
```

Once you make sure that this works (and it should) you could start componentizing this code.

Answer (score 0):

Got `Error 404` in `MVC 3`. After removing the `[HttpPost]` attribute, the code above worked fine.